# Why is my C program not counting correctly? Card game

Tags: c

I've created a card game that compares two cards of two players and determines a winner based on certain conditions. I have a function that compares the cards and returns true or false depending on the winner of the round. I call it inside a loop in my function that runs the game and the number of iterations is based on the number of cards dealt to each player. Theres something with my compare card function that allows for some rounds to fail comparison tests and I cannot tell why. The result is that my players win counts are off at the end of the game. Ive tried playing with the conditions at various points but I cannot find the issue.

Compare cards function - on seemingly random rounds the print condition at the end will execute telling me I've slipped through the other conditions

```
bool compareCards(char *card1, char *card2)
{
    char card1Face = card1[0];
    char card2Face = card2[0];

    //if card1 is A/K/Q/J and card2 is num
    if ((card1Face >= 'A' && card1Face <= 'Z') && !(card2Face >= 'A' && card2Face <= 'Z'))
    {
        return true;
    }
    //if card1 is num and card2 is A/K/Q/J
    else if (!(card1Face >= 'A' && card1Face <= 'Z') && (card2Face >= 'A' && card2Face <= 'Z'))
    {
        return false;
    }

    //if card1 and card2 both A/K/Q/J
    else if ((card1Face >= 'A' && card1Face <= 'Z') && (card2Face >= 'A' && card2Face <= 'Z'))
    {
        //test for A
        if (card1Face == 'A' && card2Face != 'A')
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (card1Face != 'A' && card2Face == 'A')
        {
            return false;
        }
        //test for K
        if (card1Face == 'K' && card2Face != 'K')
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (card1Face != 'K' && card2Face == 'K')
        {
            return false;
        }
        //test for Q
        if (card1Face == 'Q' && card2Face != 'Q')
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (card1Face != 'Q' && card2Face == 'Q')
        {
            return false;
        }
        //test for J
        if (card1Face == 'J' && card2Face != 'J')
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (card1Face != 'J' && card2Face == 'J')
        {
            return false;
        }
    } //end cards are face cards

    //If card1 and card2 are nums
    else if ((card1Face >= '1' && card1Face <= '9') && (card2Face >= '1' && card2Face <= '9'))
    {
        //if card1 is 10 and card2 is not
        if (card1Face == '1' && card2Face != '1')
        {
            return true;
        }
        //if card2 is 10 and card1 is not
        else if (card1Face != '1' && card2Face == '1')
        {
            return false;
        }
        //if card1 higher than card2
        else if (card1Face > card2Face)
        {
            return true;
        }
        //if card1 lower than card2
        else if (card1Face < card2Face)
        {
            return false;
        }
    } //end cards are nums

    //if card1 and card2 same face value
    else if (card1Face == card2Face)
    {
        char card1Suit = card1[strlen(card1) - 1];
        char card2Suit = card2[strlen(card2) - 1];

        //test for spade
        if (card1Suit == 'S')
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (card2Suit == 'S')
        {
            return false;
        }
        //test for Hearts
        if (card1Suit == 'H')
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (card2Suit == 'H')
        {
            return false;
        }
        //test for Diamonds
        if (card1Suit == 'D')
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (card2Suit == 'D')
        {
            return false;
        }
        //test for Clubs
        if (card1Suit == 'C')
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (card2Suit == 'C')
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    printf("IF THIS PRINTS UH OH");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The main playGame function

```
void playGame(void)
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    //initialize deck
    char *(*deck)[13] = initializeDeck();
    deck = shuffleDeck(deck);

    bool quit = false;

    while (1)
    {
        printHeaderDeal();

        //user input loop
        while (1)
        {
            fflush(stdin);
            char choice = getchar();

            //if enter to deal
            if (choice == '\n')
            {
                break;
            }
            //if q to quit
            else if (choice == 'q' || choice == 'Q')
            {
                printf("You chose to quit\n");
                quit = true;
                break;
            }
            //handling wrong input
            else
            {
                printf("Incorrect choice! Please choose ENTER to deal or q to quit. \n");
                scanf("%*[^\n]%*c");
            }
        } //end user input

        //if quit selected break from loop
        if (quit == true)
        {
            break;
        }

        int numCardsToDeal;

        //user selects number of cards to deal
        while (1)
        {
            printf("How many cards would you like to deal? 2-20\n");

            scanf(" %d", &numCardsToDeal);
            scanf("%*[^\n]");

            //set range = even number between 2-20
            if (numCardsToDeal >= 2 && numCardsToDeal <= 20)
            {
                if (numCardsToDeal % 2 == 1)
                {
                    printf("Players must have same amount of cards in hand. Pick an even amount to deal.\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Incorrect selection.\n");
            }
        }//end num to deal selection and validation

        //call deal cards and subtract the return value from the remaining card total
        cardsRemaining -= dealCards(deck, numCardsToDeal);

        bool result;
```

Here is where I print the players hands, call the compare function and count the wins based on each round

```
    int length1 = sizeof(player1Hand)/sizeof(player1Hand[0]);
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("Player 1 hand: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < length1; i++)
    {
        printf("[%s]", player1Hand[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    int length2 = sizeof(player2Hand)/sizeof(player2Hand[0]);
    printf("Player 2 hand: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < length2; i++)
    {
        printf("[%s]", player2Hand[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    //loop through player hands based on num of dealt cards, call compareCards on each iteration and store results of each comparison
    for (int i = 0; i < (numCardsToDeal / 2); i++)
    {
        result = compareCards(player1Hand[i], player2Hand[i]);

        if (result == true)
        {
            player1Wins++;
        }
        else if (result == false)
        {
            player2Wins++;
        }
    }

    //if run out of cards end game
    if (cardsRemaining == 0)
    {
        printf("No more cards remaining in deck. Game over.\n\n");
        break;
    }

} //end game

printf("Total wins for player 1: %d\n", player1Wins);
printf("Total wins for player 2: %d\n", player2Wins);
free(deck);
```

}

Comment: what are the cards that fail?

Comment: why don't you convert the card to a numerical value ... then you only have to do one comparison

Comment: There's a lot of repetition in you code, start by simplifying that. Also, returning a bool is not very convenient. Just make that an int so you can directly add it to player1's wins. And just assign numbers to the cards instead of characters. And why are you asking the user to input an even number? Just ask how many each player should get as a range from 1-10. Your overall implementation is not great.

Comment: @Cheatah Requirements for the assignment unfortunately.

Comment: Getting rid of repetition example.  You have this condition over and over and over: `card1Face >= 'A' && card1Face <= 'Z'`. Assign this to a variable and then use that variable instead.

Comment: Well, I don't see any of the requirements. But if the card game always has a winner, and has equal chances for either player to win, the game might as well be `rand() & 1`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will actually solve the issue, but this is too long for a comment:

There may be some other logic issues, but the first thing I've noticed is in your test for cards with numbers:

```
//If card1 and card2 are nums
else if ((card1Face >= '1' && card1Face <= '9') && (card2Face >= '1' && card2Face <= '9'))
{
     // snipped
} //end cards are nums
```

If `card1Face` and `card2Face` are both the same number, no condition will match, so it will fall through.

Note, that even though you have another `else if` test for if the cards are equal, that's *below* this case and will NOT be run, because you've already matched one `else if` condition.

So, this may not fix the issue completely, but I *think* if you move the check for `card1Face == card2Face` up to be one of the earlier checks, then you can at least remove a few cases where it will not work as you're expecting. Actually, I think you should make the equal card check the *first* check; make the `if` condition `card1Face == card2Face`, then all of the others to be `else if`.

Finally, for the sake of debugging, if it's still not working properly after that change, add an `else` block that just prints the two card values; you may start to see a pattern which will help find where other problems might be occurring.

Comment: That actually fixed the issue with the function. Nothing slips through the conditions so a big thank you for that. Still getting an extra 2 outcomes each game however so I need to figure that out still.

Comment: By 2 extra outcomes, you mean that the total number of wins reported at the end is 2 more than it should be? Like if there were 10 cards dealt, then it reports 12 total wins?

Comment: since that comment I went and figured it out, my numCardsToDeal variable was using the value set by user, but in the case that too many cards were entered for insufficient cards left in deck, I was setting it to the number of cards left in deck inside my dealing function(so not setting the global variable). The issue was my loop was using the larger value in that scenario, so my wins were being altered by the difference between the two values. If that makes sense lol. Now just to clean up some sloppy code in this program